# Why do I get java.sql may not be accessible to clients due to missing 'requires transitive'

Tags: java, javafx

I used javafx and sdk20 for my project. I have some warnings in using database.(My IDE is eclipse)

the warnings are:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The type Connection from module java.sql may not be accessible to clients due to missing  'requires transitive' dbConnect.java  /myProject/src/mypackage line 25    Java Problem
```

the db.java:

```
package mypackage;;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.*;     // Use classes in java.sql package
import java.util.Properties;

public class dbConnect {
 // init database constants
 static final String databaseDriver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
 static final String databaseURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
 static final String username = "system";
 static final String pass = "oracle";
 private Connection connection;
 private Properties properties;
 private Statement statement;

/**
 * Connect to the database  
 * 
 * @return Connection
 */
public Connection connect()
{
    if (connection == null)
    {         
        try {
            Class.forName(databaseDriver);
            connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection
                    (databaseURL, getProperties());
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return connection;
}   
.
.
.
```

modjule-info.java

```
module myProject{
   requires transitive javafx.graphics;
   requires javafx.controls;
   requires javafx.fxml;
   requires javafx.base;
   requires javafx.web;
   requires java.sql;

   opens mypackage to javafx.fxml;
   exports mypackage;
}
```

I have these warnings for ResultSet and PreparedStatement, too. I didn't type that section of code.

Comment: Do you need that method to be accessible outside of the current package? If not, give it the default visibility (instead of making it `public`). If you do need it outside of the current package (which seems like something of a design flaw), then just make `java.sql` available via a `transitive` keyword in `module-info.java`

Comment: Off-topic: please use proper naming conventions when posting your code

Comment: Created an answer from that comment.

Comment: By the way: (a) you seem to be needlessly re-inventing [`DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html), and (b) `Class.forName` has not been needed for many years — in modern Java, JDBC drivers are automatically loaded via the [Java Service Provider Interface (SPI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_provider_interface).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The warning occurs because you have a `public` method, `connect()`, defined in your public `DbConnect` class that has a return type of `Connection`. The method being `public` indicates the intention that the method can be called from anywhere, including any classes in other modules that require your module `myProject`. However, those classes will not be able to do so, because they will not be able to access the `Connection` class, which is in the `java.sql` module.

You probably don't need that method to be so widely accessible. The fact that your data is persisted to a relational database is, to a reasonable degree, an implementation detail that really shouldn't be exposed to other layers in your application.

You likely have some kind of data access class which accesses and persists domain objects and makes them available to other layers in your application (e.g. the presentation layer, with the UI etc.):

```
package myPackage;

public class DataAccessor {

    private final Connection connection ;

    public DataAccessor() {
        DbConnect dbConnect = new DbConnect();
        this.connection = dbConnect.connect();
    }

    public List<Foo> getAllFoos() throws Exception {
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM foo");
        List<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<>();
        while (result.next()) {
            Foo foo = new Foo();
            foo.setBar(result.getString("bar"))
            // ...
            foos.add(foo);
        }
        result.close();
        statement.close();
        return foos;
    }

    // etc
}
```

In almost all cases, any data access classes belong in the same package as the `DbConnect` class, and the `DbConnect.connect()` method will not be needed anywhere outside that package. That means the `connect()` method does not need to be `public`, and it is general good practice to limit visibility only to the extent needed.

In this common case you can make the method have the default "package-private" visibility, which will remove the warning:

```
public class DbConnect {

    private Connection connection;

    Connection connect() {
        if (connection == null)
        {         
            try {
                Class.forName(databaseDriver);
                connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection
                        (databaseURL, getProperties());
            }
            catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return connection;
    } 

}
```

In the (unlikely) event you really want to make the `connect()` method available publicly, you would need to make the `java.sql` module available to clients of your module. You can do this by requiring that module *transitively*:

```
module myProject{
   requires transitive javafx.graphics;
   requires javafx.controls;
   requires javafx.fxml;
   requires javafx.base;
   requires javafx.web;
   requires transitive java.sql;

   opens mypackage to javafx.fxml;
   exports mypackage;
}
```

But again, it is quite unlikely you would need to do that, or need to structure your application to make that necessary.